# When building a complex angular component, should I use attributes or transclusion?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

**The problem**

I'm trying to build a pretty complex angular component and I'm not sure about the best way to do it.

If I had to describe my component as a function the main parameters would be:

- a function that generates a list of element
- a template to render these elements (if it's an element of type A use template A and so on)
- a list of possible actions that can be applied to an element of the list (with some additional data for dysplaying them, like a text and an icon to build a button).

So to give you an example I may want to create a list with these parameters:

- function that retrieves 10 users
- template for a "user" element
- list of actions [{action: deleteUser, icon: deleteIconPath, text: 'delete'}]

I'm not sure if this is the best approach, but the component should be able to handle the list of elements by itself and should not receive it by its container.

**Possible solutions**

**1**

The first obvious solution would be to let the container manage the list of elements (first parameter) and to transclude the element template and actions.

```
<my-list>
    <elements>
        <div ng-repeat="elem in $ctrl.getData()>
            <element>
                <user e="elem"> </user>
            </element>
            <actions>
                <button action="$ctrl.delete(elem)>delete</button>
            </actions>
    <elements>
</my-list>
```

**2**

A completetly different solution would be to pass everything as an attribute of the component

```
<my-list> 
    data-getter="$ctrl.getData" 
    template="user"
    actions="[{action: deleteUser, icon: deleteIconPath, text: 'delete'}]"
</my-list>
```

**1 vs 2 comparison**

The solution 1 seems to be very standard for angular but in my case it would mean a lot of verbosity and repetition of code and I don't like it too much. The solutions 2 seems to be completely non-stardard and I'm worried that may cause some problems I cannot foresee now.

It looks like "the trend" inspired also by flux is to have some top component manage all the data and have the subcomponents access the proper data via one-way data binding. Of course just because this architecturale style is popular does not mean that is right for me, but I don't want to fight against the framework.

**The questions**

So the main questions are:

- may a sub-component getting the data by itself (of course through a service) be a problem?
- is the second solution that I described "wrong" in some basic way that I'm not able to spot now?
- is there a way for case 1 to let the transcluded code access the component elements (by that I mean moving the ng-repeat inside the component and letting the transcluded code access the reference to the ng-repeat scope)?
- do you have any alternative suggestion to build this thing?

Comment: I had some problem with sub-components which gets the data by itself. If you use the component 3-4 times each of them will make a service call and if you won't cache the data, there could be inconsistency. 
Maybe you could do both and solution 1 uses solution 2. So you can use solution 2 if the datasource changes.